# Micropython NAT between interfaces on ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, nat, micropython

I want to build a WIFI repeater using ESP8266 and [Micropython](http://micropython.org/) I already started an interface on AP mode and another on STA mode and connected the last one to my router, but seems that Micropython doesn't route the packages between interfaces and there is nothing on the [documentation](http://docs.micropython.org/) about this.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/martin-ger/esp_wifi_repeater, http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=960&sid=86f71f6f9fc73a8568d38bbf8ca064be&start=10, https://github.com/martin-ger/esp-open-lwip/tree/nat ? They're basically all using a re-configured version of lwIP with `IP_FORWARD = 1` and some other additons. May not be available in micropython.

Comment: I need to do it using micropython because I'm planning to program the ESP to do other things besides acting as a NAT router. I also tryed NodeMCU and it has forwarding disabled by default too.

Comment: For NodeMCU, have you read https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/104, http://www.areresearch.net/2015/07/first-failed-attempt-to-route-ip.html and http://www.areresearch.net/2015/10/using-esp8266-as-wifi-range-extender.html ?

Comment: I started an issue here https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/3177 and hope someone can help to incorporate this feature as soon as possible.

Comment: Couldn't you just compile a custom micropython build with IP_FORWARD turned on?

Comment: from what I've read on projects like https://github.com/martin-ger/esp_wifi_repeater I believe it's not that simple. also I believe It should be at least configurable on Micropython, that's why I opened an issue.